# Custom get_queryset with LIMIT for django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset, django-orm

I would to have a custom query to show a List of element in my admin django panel.

So, to have this I use a code like this:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
....
   def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Post.objects.filter(author_type=AuthorType.USER)
```

This work well but I need also to add a LIMIT for this queryset:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
....
   def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Post.objects.filter(author_type=AuthorType.USER)[:500]
```

But when I add the limit clause `[:500]` I have this error:

> Exception Value:   Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Django is calling another `get_queryset` method defined in `ChangeList` **after** calling your custom `get_queryset` method defined in `ModelAdmin` (see [`ChangeList` source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L42-L76)).

To apply limit in admin correctly, define your own `ChangeList`:

```py
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList

class CustomChangeList(ChangeList):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(CustomChangeList, self).get_queryset(request)

        return queryset[:5000]
```

And return this class from `ModelAdmin`:

```py
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__str__']

    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return CustomChangeList
```

Answer (score 0):

obviously somewhere is happening ordering after your slice, you should try this:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(MyAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    return qs.filter(author_type=AuthorType.USER)[:500]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36476084
@pahaz's answer is more precisely.

First, you need to create your changelist like @illagrenan

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
class CustomChangeList(ChangeList):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(CustomChangeList, self).get_queryset(request)

    return queryset[:5000]
```

and then let your modeladmin get this changelist,

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return CustomChangeList
```

I tested it and worked out, hope it can help you.