# How to get filtered queryset in django admin?

Tags: python, django

I have many different filters in Django admin:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_filter = ('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3', ... , 'field_N')
    ...
```

I need to get filtered queryset in my overridden method `changelist_view` before parent `changelist_view` is called:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_content=None):
        # here i need filtered queryset and I don`t know 
        # which filters have been applied
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)
    ...
```

if I calling `get_queryset` before `super` in `changelist_view` it returns queryset without filters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

New version of Django admin use custom objects for ChangeList view with custom get_queryset method.

As you can see in Django source:

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    ...
    ChangeList = self.get_changelist(request)

    cl = ChangeList(request, self.model, list_display,
        list_display_links, list_filter, self.date_hierarchy,
        search_fields, list_select_related, self.list_per_page,
            self.list_max_show_all, self.list_editable, self)

    # Actions with no confirmation
    if (actions and request.method == 'POST' and
            'index' in request.POST and '_save' not in request.POST):
        if selected:
            response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))
    ...
```

You must override `self.get_changelist(request)` and return your custom ChangeList with overridden `get_queryset`.

`ModelAdmin.get_changelist`:

```
def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
    """
    Returns the ChangeList class for use on the changelist page.
    """
    return MyChangeList  # PUT YOU OWERRIDEN CHANGE LIST HERE
```

`MyChangeList`:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList

class MyChangeList(ChangeList):
    def get_queryset(...):
        # if you want change get_queryset logic or add new filters
        ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # if you want add some context variable which can be accessed by 
        # {{ cl.some_context_varibale }} variable
        self.some_context_varibale = self.queryset.aggregate(Avg('price'))['price__avg']
```

Comment: A note to the location for this code in the source on github would be nice. Just handy for someone like myself that want to quickly look at the function signatures and how they are used.

Answer (score 5):

You can tamper with the response returned by the original [`changelist_view`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/119f227aa62885f12cd7dd2558a62148d02adbb4/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1918) call. For example, to add some extra template context data using the *queryset* **after** it's filtered by the admin's [`ChangeList`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9c19aff7c7561e3a82978a272ecdaad40dda5c00/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L54) instance:

```py
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    # Obtain the original response from Django
    response = super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)

    # Extract the final queryset from the ChangeList object
    change_list = response.context_data['cl']
    queryset = change_list.queryset

    # Do stuff with the queryset
    stats = self.get_stats(queryset)

    # Inject a new key in the template context data
    response.context_data['stats'] = stats

    return response
```